# About parametrizing base template page in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following problem, there is a base template "base.html" which defines default header and body information, which will be used by other pages.
The base page contains the rendered parameter, which depends on the request time in a non trivial way.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    ...
    {% block head_stuff %} {% endblock %}
    ...
    </head>

    <body>
    ...
    <p>Parameter that depends on the request time</p>
    ...
    {% block body_stuff %} {% endblock %}
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The pages that use it look like:

**a.html** **b.html** **c.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head_stuff %} ... {% endblock %}
{% block body_stuff %} ... {% endblock %}
```

What I'd like to do is to render `a.html`, `b.html`, `c.html` without passing informations about that parameter to these pages in their views or templates.
In absence of inheritance, one would call `render` function by passing the parameter to a context, but in this case no views are used to construct the `base.html`.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: can  you please expand on your question. From the examples you have given you are not using any parameters within your page level templates anyway nor are you within your base template.  The page level templates are also wrong. You do not need the opening DOCTYPE tag or the closing HTML tag as those are included in your base template. You just need to start with the extends and then have named block sections

Comment: child pages are fixed.
the base template isn't a static page and it's content depends on time, basically that's the problem, I want understand how to deal with it. I call child pages by specifying their url, but not the base's one, and still have the base page that changes depending on time, so depending on a parameter.

Comment: Could you describe what changes over time and where that data is from? Does it relate to the view/views that handle rendering of the page? It sounds like you may have one view where you pass a parameter which then decides which page template to use, is that correct?  If it is and the dynamic logic used by the base template is not determined by that view then  consider using a custom_context processor or even custom middleware in order to make those variables available all of the time. - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: A context processor is a function that takes ```request``` as an argument and returns a dictionary. The contents of this dictionary are then appened to the context of every template. So if you had a context process or ```def my_example(request):
    return dict(name="steve", dynamic_thing=some_other_function())``` then the templates could access these using ```{{ name }}``` and ```{{ dynamic_thing }}```

Comment: I have a txt file, that contains lines; each line is selected at a specified time range that I can decide by a view that controls the logic and returns the string. In fact only the base page is modified, changing that specific line in <p> tags.
The problem is that I'm sure the file with lines will change, so I can't decide which base page template to choose, actually I need to generate it in some way, possibly when calling child pages by accessing them.
A custom contest processor should do its work. I'll try and tell you, anyway it seems a good solution for me.

Comment: Nice solution, it works. I can close the question by accepting your suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context processor is a function that takes request as an argument and returns a dictionary. The contents of this dictionary are then appended to the context of every template. So if you had a context process or

```
def my_example(request):
    return dict(
        name="steve",
        dynamic_thing=some_other_function()
    )
```

Then the templates could access these using `{{ name }}` and `{{ dynamic_thing }}`